# HTML5 Canvas clearRect isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I'm trying to have an 'X' appear on the screen and go across every second, but the previous 'X's don't go away when I draw the new ones, a whole path of 'X's stays behind and I want it to just be one that moves across in 60px increments. Obviously there must be something having to do with paths and such that I don't know about, here's my code:

```js
//ctx is already defined as the canvas context and works fine
var bx = 0;
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
setInterval(function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.moveTo(bx*60   ,0);
    ctx.lineTo(bx*60+60,60);
    ctx.moveTo(bx*60+60,0);
    ctx.lineTo(bx*60   ,60);
    ctx.stroke();
    bx++;
},1000);
```

```html
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to begin and close path. Your canvas go to clear but all your lines will be every iteration rerendered.

```
//ctx is already defined as the canvas context and works fine
var bx = 0;
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
setInterval(function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath(); // begin
    ctx.moveTo(bx*60   ,0);
    ctx.lineTo(bx*60+60,60);
    ctx.moveTo(bx*60+60,0);
    ctx.lineTo(bx*60   ,60);
    ctx.closePath(); // close
    ctx.stroke();
    bx++;
},1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
//ctx is already defined as the canvas context and works fine
var bx = 0;
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
setInterval(function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(bx * 60, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(bx * 60 + 60, 60);
    ctx.moveTo(bx * 60 + 60, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(bx * 60, 60);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    bx++;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```